# Pass a variable to Jquery's parameter as if it was a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('.reporte, .maquinaria').on('change', function () {
    var clase = $(this).hasClass('reporte') ? "reporte" : "maquinaria";
    var item = {};

    $(clase).each(function () {
        item[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
    });
    json[clase].splice(0, 1);
    json[clase].push({
        item
    });
    console.log(json[clase])
});
```

if I make something like this:

```
$('.clase').each(function () {
    item[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
});
```

it works. But I want to pass the class with the var clase that I already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class needs a `.` before it in the selector. `$("." + clase)`

Comment: Thanks it worked! i'm new with Jquey and i didn't know that i could made something like that